# Open link in WeChat browser from non-WeChat browser

Tags: html, wechat

Trying to integrate wechat service so if I need to open a link in my mobile site webpage in Wechat app what will be the proper Scheme prefix for that.

Already gone through these links 
[How do I link to wechat from a webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35425553/how-do-i-link-to-wechat-from-a-webpage)
and
https://www.zhihu.com/question/30616809?sort=created
so WeChat does have a URI scheme that can be used from a browser. The scheme prefix is weixin://.

But not sure which one of these can be used. I tried 
weixin://Dl/businessWebview/link/url=google.com
it opened we chat app but then shows error - 'Unable to redirect'

Comment: Its more than 8 months I have not got any answer to my question so I think I should post an alternative here if in case it helps anyone.  Convert that link to QRCode, display it to user with a message to save it in their mobile and then extract it in wechat app.

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to start wechat app using an URL or from an external web browser.

`weixin://` is used by wechat only inside its web browser, for example to start the payment process and this type of URL's are meaningless outside of wechat.