# Is there any method to share text from mobile web to wechat by sharing button?

Tags: mobile-website, wechat

I am looking for wechat sharing function like how whatsapp does.

```
href="whatsapp://send?text=http://www.example.com"
```

Based on my research, most of them will be encoded in QR code and scan the QR code with wechat scanner. Is there a way to share the text directly to friend when click on sharing button just like how whatsapp does?

Answer (score 1):

Wechat doesn't have any official deep linking URL for sending a text. However, if you can add some JavaScript Code in your mobile web, you can achieve the share functionality.

Check out [`Send to chat`](http://admin.wechat.com/wiki/index.php?title=JS_SDK_DOCUMENT#API_for_Obtaining_Send_Status_for_.22Send_to_Chat.22_and_Customizing_Sharing_Contents) documentation on Wechat JS SDK.

#### From JS SDK Documentation:-

```
wx.onMenuShareAppMessage({
    title: '', // Sharing title
    desc: '', // Sharing description
    link: '', // Sharing link
    imgUrl: '', // Sharing image URL
    type: '', // Sharing type, such as “music”, “video “ or “link”. It is “link” by default.
    dataUrl: '', // The data URL should be provided for items of type “music” or “video”. It is null by default.
    success: function () { 
        // Callback function executed after a user confirms sharing
    },
    cancel: function () { 
        // Callback function executed after a user cancels sharing
    }
});
```

---

We do have some unofficial deep linking URL like you mentioned. But it may stop work anytime if Wechat decided to change it.

Here is some of them below, sadly I don't know any URL to share a text to chat.

- `weixin://` - to open Wechat app (if installed)
- `weixin://dl/chat` - to open chat screen of Wechat
- `weixin://dl/moments` - to open user moements
- `weixin://dl/profile` - to open user profile
- `weixin://dl/settings` - to open settings page

Comment: Take a look at this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35425553/how-do-i-link-to-wechat-from-a-webpage

As for what it's said there, WeChat banned this URI methods to share from websites.

I haven't got to share an URL to WeChat so far. But some method there must be.