# Does anyone got this problem with wechat links like weixin://dl/chat?{toID}?

Tags: html, url-scheme, wechat

I'm implemented solution from this anwser (https://stackoverflow.com/a/35576003/22370001), and for a time it was working perfectly, but about 3 weeks ago it's stoped to work.

When app is opened, i got screen with error: "Sorry, this page is not available."

Does anyone get same problem?

I tried different accounts links and got same problem, so i'm not sure if problem in some particular profile.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask].

Comment: Sounds like a question for weChat customer service

Comment: Yes, i asked them about two weeks ago, but haven't got an anwser yet.

So i interested if someone else get same problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.